# Advantages/Disadvantages of Passing a Function into Deferred's Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

In playing with Deferred's I see many different combinations of use.  Most are the same, but occasionally I see ones that differ slightly.

FOR EXAMPLE...

**NORMALLY, I SEE THIS**:
Here we are merely using the Deferred.

```
// NORMALLY I SEE THIS...
function doSomething(){

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var myClass = new MyClass();

    myClass.doSomething(function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

**OCCASSIONALLY, I SEE THIS:**
Here we are passing a function into the Deferred's constructor...then using it.

```
// SOMETIMES I SEE THIS...
function doSomething() {

    var deferred = $.Deferred(function (deferred) {

        //Q: Is there an advantage to doing this instead?
        //Q: Is this a mis-use?
        var myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.doSomething(function () {
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

MY QUESTION IS:

- Is there an advantage to doing the 2nd one instead?
- Is this a mis-use of the constructor?
- Does this practice create issue I just haven't seen yet?

I have yet to see any issue's arise from method 2.  So, I'm looking for real insight here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an advantage to doing the 2nd one instead?

No, unless you enjoy callbacks which defeats the purpose of promises.

---

> Is this a mis-use of the constructor?

Nope. [jQuery deffered doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

> jQuery.Deferred( [beforeStart ] )
>
> ```
> beforeStart
> Type: Function( Deferred deferred )
> A function that is called just before the constructor returns.
> ```

---

> Does this practice create issue I just haven't seen yet?

No it doesn't, unless you intended to use `myClass` somewhere else which won't be possible since it is defined within your callback.

**Conclusion:**

In the end, it's more of a personal preference. Solution 1 just seems more clean to be honest.